# Details about 'Charting`ScaledTicks' and double axes

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am plotting the data from a sensor; the vertical axis shows the force `F`, and the horizontal axis corresponds to time. I would like to have a secondary vertical axis showing the acceleration `a` (related by the famous equation `F=ma`, where `m` is the probe's mass).

As far as I understand, this can be easily done by the function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``, but I can't find enough documentation to understand how to use it. Any direction would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm including an implementation based on @Daniel Huber's code, but it is not handling the secondary axis properly since some of the ticks are out of the range of the original plot.

```
d1 = Table[3 Sin[p], {p, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}];
mass = 0.5;
FrameTicksForForce = {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3};
FrameTicksForAcceleration = FrameTicksForForce/mass;

ListLinePlot[d1, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{FrameTicksForForce, FrameTicksForAcceleration}, 
   Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Force [N]", 
    "Acceleration [m/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(2\)]\)]"}, {"Time \
[s]", None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Post your data (or at least a representative sample of the data)  and the code (`InputForm`) that you have used.

Comment: The curve of the acceleration will be identical to the force with the exception of a scale factor equal to the mass

Comment: @DanielHuber I know that, thanks for the reminder. I want to add a secondary axis showing the proper acceleration units.

Comment: I added an example for 2 axes using "Frame"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an arbitrary example for 2 curves with different units and different y axes:

```
d1 = Table[Sin[p], {p, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}];
d2 = 2 d1;

ListLinePlot[{d1, d2}, PlotRange -> {-Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {-Pi, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2, Pi}},
    Automatic}]
```

[image]